# What's the best way to temporarily disable every field of an Angular form?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, formgroups

I know how to do that in two ways ([demo of both here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yxsrxa?file=src%2Fmain.ts)). The two are applicable both to template-driven and reactive forms because both of them rely on the `FormGroup` API.

### `formGroup.enable()` and `formGroup.disable()`

```html
<form ngForm>
    <input ngModel name=name [disabled]=fieldIsDisabled() />
</form>
```

```js
this.ngForm.form.enable();
this.ngForm.form.disable();
```

This is the approach I wish I could use if it weren't for two problems:

- `formGroup.enable()` ignores the fields' `[disabled]` directive value, therefore forcing all the fields to become enabled when other controls might be saying it should stay disabled. This is shown in the linked demo.
- If the value in the `[disabled]` directive changes, the form fields won't care if I called `enable()` or `disable()`, which can cause fields to become enabled when I don't want them to.

I wish it instead worked like a control variable, like the next solution:

### State variable present across all fields

Here, the `formIsDisabled` signal controls the entire form's "disabled" state. It fixes the previous solution's problem.

```html
<form ngForm>
    <input ngModel name=name [disabled]="formIsDisabled() || nameDisabled()"/>
    <input ngModel name=address [disabled]=formIsDisabled() />
</form>
```

The disadvantage is that the control variable must be applied to every single field, which feels **redundant and error-prone**... but it's still the least bad option, to my knowledge.

#### Questions: is there a better way to achieve this? What reasons are there for the `formGroup.enable()` and `formGroup.disable()` methods to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve that only using the DISABLED status:

For simplicity Let's say you have 1 dimensional reactive form. First, you need to disable all currently enabled fields and collect the disabled fields' keys:

```
    const alreadyDisadledKeys: string[] = [];
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((key) => {
      const control = this.form.controls[key];
      if (control.status === 'DISABLED') {
        alreadyDisadledKeys.push(key);
      } else {
        control.disable();
      }
    });
```

alreadyDisadledKeys can be stored somewhere. Then enable the form again, excluding alreadyDisadledKeys:

```
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((key) => {
      const control = this.form.controls[key];
      if (!alreadyDisadledKeys.includes(key)) {
        control.enable();
      }
    });
```

The same approach can be extended for more complicated forms too, you would need to do the same steps:

- Collet all disabled fields ( or all enabled fields if you prefer )
- Iterate over the form and disable the rest of the fields
- Iterate again and enable previously enabled fields

> What reasons are there for the formGroup.enable() and formGroup.disable() methods to work like this?

Here I can only guess. I think it's because Angular treats DISABLED more of a status than an attribute.

Comment: I see a problem with this solution. for example, with the first template in my question: `fieldIsDisabled()` is returning true, so field "name" is already disabled; the mechanism you suggested for disabling the form is initiated, so "name" is stored in `alreadyDisabledKeys`; meanwhile, `fieldIsDisabled()` starts returning true, causing the field to become enabled when the mechanism for enabling hasn't been initiated

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue you've described. What about using reactive forms? In this case you can control when to disable / enable the controls. If `fieldIsDisabled()` can change at any time - I believe for template-driven forms "State variable present across all fields" is the only reliable solution.